# How to set two Java Arraylist values into one Java object?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an issue while working with java ArrayList. Here is the brief description:

1. By making a web service call, I will get all the videos around 900+ as Java objects. These Java objects are lacking some of the required information. So I am again making a call to another web service by passing the video id. This also returns Java objects.
2. I am storing the first web service call values and the second web service call values into two different Java ArrayLists as below:

   List mediaList = new ArrayList();
   List mediaVOs = new ArrayList();
3. Finally I am writing a method by passing two lists and setting those values into one java object. This should return the total objects around 942. But this is returning some odd number 887364 instead of 942 count.

Please help me resolving the issue. Here is the code:

```
        client = getClient();
        if (client != null) {
            List<MediaEntry> mediaList = getAllMedia();
            if (mediaList.size() >= 1) {
                System.out.println("Total Media ------>" + mediaList.size());
                MetadataListResponse metadataListResponse = null;
                Media mediaVO = null;
                List<List<String>> metadataValues = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                List<String> categoriesList = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> accountNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> ownerNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> languageList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(MediaEntry entry:mediaList) {
                    if(entry != null) {
                        metadataListResponse = getMetadata(entry.id);
                        if (metadataListResponse.totalCount >= 1) {
                            mediaVO = new Media();
                            List<Metadata> metadataObjs = metadataListResponse.objects;
                            if (metadataObjs != null
                                    && metadataObjs.size() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < metadataObjs.size(); i++) {
                                    Metadata metadata = metadataObjs
                                            .get(i);
                                    if (metadata != null) {
                                        if (metadata.xml != null) {
                                            metadataValues = parseXml(metadata.xml);
                                            if (metadataValues.size() != 0) {
                                                categoriesList = metadataValues
                                                        .get(0);
                                                accountNamesList = metadataValues.get(1);
                                                ownerNamesList = metadataValues.get(2);
                                                countryList = metadataValues.get(3);
                                                languageList = metadataValues.get(4);

                                                if (categoriesList.size() == 1) {
                                                    for (String categoryName : categoriesList) {
                                                        //System.out
                                                        //.println("categoryName"+categoryName);
                                                        mediaVO.setCategories(categoryName);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (accountNamesList.size() == 1) {

                                                    for (String accountName : accountNamesList) {
                                                        //System.out
                                                        //.println("accountName"+accountName);
                                                        mediaVO.setAccountName(accountName);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (ownerNamesList.size() == 1) {

                                                    for (String ownerName : ownerNamesList) {
                                                        //System.out
                                                        //.println("ownerName"+ownerName);
                                                        mediaVO.setOwnerName(ownerName);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (countryList.size() == 1) {
                                                    for (String country : countryList) {
                                                        //System.out
                                                        //.println("country"+country);
                                                        mediaVO.setCountry(country);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (languageList.size() == 1) {
                                                    for (String language : languageList) {
                                                        //System.out
                                                        //.println("language"+language);
                                                        mediaVO.setLanguage(language);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        mediaVOs.add(mediaVO);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("mediaVOs.size()------>"+mediaVOs.size());
                List<Media> medias = setMediaVO(mediaList, mediaVOs);
                if(medias.size() >= 1) {
                    System.out.println("Final medias size ------>"+medias.size());
                    mediaXml = convertToXml(medias);
                    System.out.println("Final Media XML converted ------->"+mediaXml);
                    Document doc = convertStrToDoc(mediaXml);
                }
            }
        }


private List<Media> setMediaVO(List<MediaEntry> mediaList,List<Media> mediaList1) {
    if(mediaList.size() >= 1) {
        if(mediaList1.size() >= 1) {
            for(MediaEntry media:mediaList)  {
                for(Media media1:mediaList1) {
                    Media mediaVO = new Media();
                    MediaType mediaType = media.mediaType;
                    mediaVO.setMediaId(media.id);
                    mediaVO.setMediaName(media.name);
                    mediaVO.setMediaDesc(media.description);
                    mediaVO.setCreatedDate(media.createdAt);
                    mediaVO.setCreditUserName(media.creditUserName);
                    mediaVO.setDataUrl(media.dataUrl);
                    mediaVO.setDownloadUrl(media.dataUrl);
                    mediaVO.setDuration(media.duration);
                    mediaVO.setEndDate(media.endDate);
                    mediaVO.setEntitledUsersEdit(media.entitledUsersEdit);
                    mediaVO.setEntitledUsersPublish(media.entitledUsersPublish);
                    mediaVO.setLastPlayedAt(media.lastPlayedAt);
                    mediaVO.setMediaType(mediaType.toString());
                    mediaVO.setUpdatedDate(media.updatedAt);
                    mediaVO.setPlays(media.plays);
                    mediaVO.setViews(media.views);
                    mediaVO.setCategories(media1.getCategories());
                    mediaVO.setAccountName(media1.getAccountName());
                    mediaVO.setOwnerName(media1.getOwnerName());
                    mediaVO.setCountry(media1.getCountry());
                    mediaVO.setLanguage(media1.getLanguage());
                    medias.add(mediaVO);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return medias;
}
```

Thanks,
Raji

Comment: 887364 isn't odd at all, it's 942² : it means you have one too much loop level

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, the code you've included is both too much (lots of irrelevant code) and too little (it's incomplete - we can't reproduce anything using it). Please provide a [mcve] for us to help you with. Note that it shouldn't need to make any web service calls. My *guess* is that you should be matching entries in the two lists by ID, whereas currently you're producing the cross-join...

Comment: Maybe you´d be better if you´d be using a `Map<Integer, String>`.

Comment: You're not matching videos to each other, so you're creating a combination of all of the videos. This produces 942*942 objects, being the 887364 number that you're seeing.

Comment: Oh god, please reduce indentation! Tips: Replace `if (a) { if (b) {` by `if (a && b) {`. Outsource parts to other methods. Where possible, replace `if (x) { /* many lines */ }` by `if (!x) return/continue;`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will try fixing this issue. Will post proper code further.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here :

```
for(MediaEntry media:mediaList)  {
            for(Media media1:mediaList1) {
```

For each MediaEntry, you're looping on each Media, which means you'll execute the code inside 942 * 942 times, while what you want is to execute it 942 times. You've got to match MediaEntries with Media and execute the code once.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain this in a way where everybody understands what i mean.

The problem is indeed the fact that you multiply 942 by itself.
This happens cause of the following code:

```
private List<Media> setMediaVO(List<MediaEntry> mediaList,List<Media> mediaList1) {
    if(mediaList.size() >= 1) {
        if(mediaList1.size() >= 1) {
            for(MediaEntry media:mediaList)  {
                for(Media media1:mediaList1) {
                    //Do stuff 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return medias;
}
```

Here you loop though medialist 1 for each item in medialist and do stuff with it.
At the end of this code you add each entry found in medialist 1 to a other list but this happend 942 times per item in the first list.
And since that list has 942 items you get the "odd" number of 887.364.